# Where to buy running shoe sole replacements?

Tags: footwear, shoes, running

I've got a comfy pair of runners that I primarily use for walking.  I've put them through the wash a few times and they come out spotless.  The only ware is on sole, which appears to be 1/2 cm thick or so rubber grip, glued onto the bottom of the shoe.

I'm trying to find somewhere that sells this kind of thing but only find inner sole replacements.

Suggestions please?

Comment: For most running shoes I know, replacing the sole instead of buying a new pair of shoes would not pay off. In which condition is the sole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally quite hard to replace the actual soles for trainers. You could have a look online or just buy a new pair of trainers. If you go to a tailors or shoe makers they may be able to do it also.

Comment: Yep, replacing insoles are easy, but once actual soles are ruined - easier to get a fresh pair rather than try to repair old one sadly(I'm usually getting 2 pairs at the same time, If it's shoes I'm confident with. My latest ones are Hoka Speedgoat 5 from Run United https://rununited.com/ , gotta say that EVA soles are pretty meh on those, probably going to need a new ones in 4-5 months since those get deflated really quick...)